# AutoStart Popup when some code are true

Tags: development

I have got a code:

`if (sumaProcentow > 8) 
{ e.Cell.Style.Add("background-color", "#FF0000");
 e.Cell.CssClass = "dni_swiateczne"; }`
I wont when this code are true to auto post popap in the Sharepoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grzegorz,

You can take a HiddenField on web part and set its value to true inside your code:

```
if (sumaProcentow > 8)
{
    HiddenField1.Value = "1";
}
```

Now in your web part in `<script>` write this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function callPopupOrNot()
{
   if (document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>').value == "1")
   {
        test();
    }
}

function test() { 
   var webUrl = "<%= SPContext.Current.Web.Url %>";
   SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({ 
       url: webUrl + "/Lists/Announcements/NewForm.aspx", 
       title: "Add item", 
       allowMaximize: true, 
       showClose: true, 
       width: 800, 
       height: 600, 
       dialogReturnValueCallback: silentCallback }); 
 };

function silentCallback(dialogResult, returnValue) { } 

function refreshCallback(dialogResult, returnValue) { SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK); } } 

setTimeout(callPopupOrNot(),100);

</script>
```

Let me know if you have any questions! setTimeout is javascript function, which calls the callPopupOrNot function after 100 milliseconds...